# Debugging results in numerous errors. The code worked well when I used it on school computer. But not on my own PC

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I cannot build the executable from this program.

I tried adding Windows universal CRT SDK, or changing windows SDK, but it just didn't work.

Here are the errors I got:

```
variable _ACRTIMP is not a type name
The Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.o was not found. Install the requested version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".
the global scope has no "_Mbstatet"
the global scope has no "Exit"
the global scope has no "wscanf"
the global scope has no "wprintf"
the global scope has no "memset"
```

And here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool      isNew = true,   isNew2 = true, isNew3 = true;
    bool      isAuto = true,   isAuto2 = true, isAuto3 = true;

    //working variables
    float     totalprice = 0.00;
    int       choice = 0;
    bool      isValid = true;

    float     baseprice = 40000.0, baseprice2 = 293200.0, baseprice3 = 35000.0;
    float     taxrate = 1.0875;

    short int year = 2019, year2 = 2019, year3 = 2019;
    int       mileage = 20, mileage2 = 20, mileage3 = 20;

    string    make = "BMW", make2 = "Porsche", make3 = "Ford";
    string    model = "x3", model2 = "911 GT2 RS", model3 = "Mustang";
    string    color = "Red", color2 = "Grey", color3 = "Yellow";
    string    Engine = "v8", engine2 = "liter Boxer", engine3 = "V8";
    string    dname = "Statecars";

    //Display the welcome message
    cout << "Welcome to " << dname << "!" << endl;
    cout << "We sell the following cars! " << endl;
    cout << "1. " << year << " " << color << " " << make << " " << model << endl;
    cout << "2. " << year2 << " " << color2 << " " << make2 << " " << model2 << endl;
    cout << "3. " << year3 << " " << color3 << " " << make3 << " " << model3 << endl;
    cout << "Enter your car choice [1-3]?:  ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case (1):
        totalprice = baseprice * taxrate;
        break;
    case (2):
        totalprice = baseprice2 * taxrate;
        break;
    case (3):
        totalprice = baseprice3 * taxrate;
        break;
    default:
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
    }

    if (isValid)
    {
        cout << "The total price is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << totalprice;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "invalid choice!" << endl;
    }


    system("pause"); //keep the output screen open

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. If you have a question, [edit] your posting in order to ask it. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: We can only see the errors *after* you tried to fix the problem.  You made it worse.  Note how "10.0.17134.o" is mis-spelled, it ends on the letter o instead of the digit 0.  Impossible to guess how you did that and what the real problem was, you'll have to copy everything again from the working machine and this time not try to fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 was not found.You should downloaded the SDK .

Run Visual Studio installer click on modify, and select Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0) under SDKs,libraries and framework in individual components tab of the installer.

[image]